# ATI/AMD Driver "Adapter not supported" strange issue

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon, 14.10

Yesterday I installed the AMD/ATI Official driver (Omega version 14.501.1003-x86.x86_64)from AMD's official site. The installation completed successfully using "Install Driver 14.501.1003 on X.Org 6.9 or later 64-bit". No issues till then.

I reinstalled Ubuntu 14.10 due to some reason. Now in the newly installed Ubuntu when I try to install the same AMD Driver 14.501.1003 a dialogue box pop up saying:

"Your graphics driver is not supported by this driver. Installation will not proceed."

Earlier there was no such error.

GPU: AMD/ATI Radeon HD 6630M

Linux kernel: 3.16
X.org: 1.16

Q.1 Why is this error showing on the newly installed 14.10 (Utopic Unicorn)
Q.2 How to solve it so that I can reinstall the AMD driver